# AJAX Call to ASP.Net Server Side Web service method problem

Tags: jquery

i am trying to make AJAX Call to ASP.Net Server Side Web service method the problem it dose not give me error or exception

i am trying to execute a peace of code when the user click button i want it ti call my custom service and execute it then return me the result in another control [Grid View ]

the code is :

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function myfunction() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "My method",
        data: Bind Data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: alert();,

    });
}

</script>
```

the problem is it dose not work i try the fire bug and it do not call the method

Comment: are you specifying the `url` correct? and what is Bind Data in `data:Bind Data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well the question is not clear if you did not make some thing like that before you need to be  more specific in your problem you are trying to make a AJAX Call to ASP.Net Server Side Web service method using j query  I have a similier post to the same problem in my blog have a look :

http://eslamsoliman.blogspot.com/2011/07/make-ajax-call-to-aspnet-server-side.html

i think that the problem in your jquery code in the URL part and in the success part ,mark as answered if it helps :)

Comment: you article was very useful thanks a lot and i will take by your advice in the future

Comment: your welcome .and if you searched on stackover flow you can fin similar question :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059621/jquery-execute-ajax-call-from-ajaxcomplete
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027960/jquery-ajax-call-to-asp-net-webservice-fails-server-return-500-error

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/path/to/webservice",
        data: {data:data}, //not sure what Data Bind is?
        dataType: "json",        
        success:function(data){
            alert("success");
       },
        error:function(jxhr){
           alert(jxhr.responseText);
       }

    });
```

[`jquery ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

also here is a useful link [**POSTing JSON Data to MVC Controllers**](http://lozanotek.com/blog/archive/2010/04/16/posting_json_data_to_mvc_controllers.aspx)

Comment: thank you very much ,you answer was great and i found an article that explain my case exactly :)